# I have got a built in Bluetooth in my laptop but I can't find it in the Device Manager

Tags: windows-7, acer-aspire, drivers

My Acer Aspire 9303WSMi has got a Bluetooth button as shown in the picture below:

[image]

I have installed Windows 7 on my laptop and I don't have any copy of drivers. I looked at the Acer's website, as they only support Win XP and Windows Vista for this model, and I downloaded Bluetooth drivers available there for Vista. When I run `Setup.exe`, it says "No Bluetooth Device Found". I opened up Device Manager to see if I can find Bluetooth device there but no luck OR perhaps I don't know where to look?

Is it possible to set it up? Can anybody help me set it up, please?

Please see I don't have CD or backup of Acer eRecovery or other software that come pre-installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I go through other forums, most of the users say that

> "It has Bluetooth Switch button but we need to purchase the device to make it functional"

and also I referred the **[Acer Aspire 9303WSMi](http://www.acerdirect.co.uk/Acer_Aspire_9303WSMi_LX.AWR0X.044/version.asp)** Technical specifications, it clearly mentioned that

### "NO BLUETOOTH"

Comment: Yes, Its a bit confusing. Thx